# swfupload not working with Flash 10

Tags: jquery, flash, swfupload, flash-10

I'm using jquery and swfupload in order to upload files and photos.

Worked fine till now, but it seems it doesn't like Flash 10. 
It stopped working the moment I upgraded Flash.

Anybody had this problem? How did you solve it?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[swfupload download page @ google code](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/)

It's already fixed. Flash 10 messed with the methods to get the file browser window open.  You'll have to go download the new swfupload.

Comment: Do we need to move to the Beta version to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer to the question, but I would like to share this..

Using hacky flash uploader workarounds is a really bad idea in general. I would suggest people to switch over to decent javascript alternatives. Flash adoption is already falling down rapidly, and with the current browsers developing awesomely fast, we can just trust on native browser stuff like javascript, xml and json. No more third party plugins, I use qq.FileUploader quite often, but I'm sure there will be lots of good alternatives.